# Milestones - Service Cloud

Tags: case, servicecloud, casemilestone

Is it good to have milestones as a countdown for internal processes? For example, let's say we don't have sla with a customer, but we want to have internally a rule to support that we will support him within 2 hours. Are milestones the way to go or is it not a best practice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your scenario, the Milestone will work,

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_milestone_tracker.htm&type=0

The above link will guide you to set up a milestone.

===================

If more than 24 hours remain on a milestone, the countdown displays in days (for example, 1d). When fewer than 24 hours remain, the countdown format switches to hours/minutes/seconds.

For this, an idea is also raised,

https://trailblazer.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A0000003WA7QAM

Business Hours Work in Entitlement Management will work for you.

Try it,

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=entitlements_business_hours.htm&type=5

https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=customize_supporthours_guidelines.htm&type=5

I hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you so much!!!